# Adding scrollbar arrows to Adwaita (default) on GTK2 apps

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk, scrollbar, gtk-2

I am using Ubuntu 22.10 Desktop. I have only the default themes installed on my system. Currently, I am using **Adwaita (default)** which does *not* have arrows at the two ends of vertical or horizontal window scrollbars.

I have tested the other themes; only **HighContrast** and **HighContrastInverse** seem to provide the arrows I need. However, these *high contrast* themes are not appropriate for me. **Adwaita (default)** is just fine, except for the missing arrows in scrollbars.

I have tried a few solutions provided on the Internet (like [this](https://www.slsmk.com/adding-scrollbars-and-buttons-to-desktop-theme/)) that try to create a file like `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and put the necessary CSS declarations, but these do not work.

What is the recommended method to *locally* modify a theme for GTK2 applications and add these scrollbar arrows?

#### Update

Actually, it turns out that the above-mentioned action *does* work for GTK3 applications. But, **my application that needs these arrows uses GTK2**.

I tried locations like `~/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`, `~/.gtkrc`, and `~/.gtkrc-2.0`, but it didn't help.

Editing directly the file `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/main.rc` and commenting out the lines:

```
GtkScrollbar::has-backward-stepper = 0
GtkScrollbar::has-forward-stepper = 0
```

seems to help, but I want to do it on user basis (by setting their values to `1`).

Comment: This is just from memory, but maybe you could add some code to `~/.gtkrc-2.0`?

Comment: Which are these gtk2 applications, preferably small ones?

Comment: Lazarus (FreePascal) applications. See: https://wiki.freepascal.org/GTK3_Interface

Comment: I used `apt rdepends libgtk2.0-0 | less` to find a few. A convenient one to check with (for me) is pcmanfm.

Comment: You linked to a GTK3 application?

Comment: No. I am using only the default Lazarus configuration, which is gtk2 currently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have put your custom settings in
*.gtkrc-2.0.mine*,
but your *.gtkrc-2.0* is not including *.gtkrc-2.0.mine* (or is being overwritten by your DE),
then instead include *.gtkrc-2.0.mine* near the bottom of **/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc**

e.g

```
.
.
# local settings
include "/home/username/.gtkrc-2.0.mine"

# And hand over the control to the theme files
include "main.rc"
include "apps.rc"
include "hacks.rc"
```

Alternatively, for a global solution,
you can change any scroll related settings in
**/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/main.rc**

e.g

```
GtkScrollbar::slider-width = 20
GtkRange::stepper-size = 20
GtkScrollbar::stepper-size         = 20
GtkScrollbar::has-backward-stepper = 1
GtkScrollbar::has-forward-stepper  = 1
```

Also, comment out the block beneath;

```
# Disable arrows for qt in scrollbars
```

otherwise the arrow graphics will be blocked.

Comment: Actually the file `~/.gtkrc-2.0` works, but I could only set the `GtkScrollbar::stepper-size = 16` value successfully. But, no triangles (arrows) are shown so far; only blank clickable rectangles on both ends of the scrollbar.

Comment: My bad, I thought you indicated a location problem. If you want to see the arrows, you could comment out the block beginning with; '# Disable arrows for qt in scrollbars' , in main.rc, but this would not be a local fix.

Comment: That worked @Humpity. You can expand your answer with your comment, so I can accept it. Thank you!